# How can I love someone that I do not truly know or understand?

Tags: nature-of-god

Can you love someone when a big portion of his personality is a mystery or beyond your comprehension?

A picture of God is in my mind, portrayed by the books I've read but it's not the whole picture. I can follow, respect and trust God but to love is something way deeper. I remember the love of my youth and how my heart used to pound whenever I saw her...

- How can someone achieve that level of intimacy with God?

Comment: No one truly and fully understands anyone, not even ourselves...

Comment: @curiousdannii All you need is data and trials, if you live with someone your whole life, you can even predict their actions.

Comment: Intimacy takes time. It is not based on head knowledge but is experiential. Love is reciprocated after we experience the love of God for us: "We love him, because he first loved us" (1 John :19 KJV).

Comment: Jesus said, "Whoever has my commands and obeys them, he is the one who loves me." Jn.14:21. John wrote, "But if anyone obeys his word, God's love is truly made complete in him." 1 Jn.2:5. [I think Lesley missed out ch. 4 in her ref.] Don't let emotional feelings be your gauge for whether you love God or not! They can fluctuate like the weather!

Comment: Love is not foundationally a feeling but a choice of action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When asked what was the most important commandment, Jesus gave an answer most pertinent.

> And one of the scribes came up and heard them disputing with one
> another, and seeing that he answered them well, asked him, “Which
> commandment is the most important of all?” Jesus answered, “The most
> important is, ‘Hear, O Israel: The Lord our God, the Lord is one. And
> **you shall love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your
> soul and with all your mind and with all your strength**.’ The second is
> this: ‘You shall love your neighbor as yourself.’ There is no other
> commandment greater than these.” (Mark 12:28-31, ESV)

Would God command what is impossible? If loving Him is uppermost in His desire for us, would he not provide us everything necessary for realizing this?

Such a loving relationship with God is not formed instantly. As with human friendships, it grows over time, or withers through neglect. The Lord provides many supports to us. If we avail ourselves of them, our love for Him will grow.

I am not wise enough to list all these supports, but here are some:

1. Other believers who share things about how they cultivate their relationship with God.
2. The Holy Spirit, which by residing inside us can speak to the deepest parts of our soul.
3. The Bible, which gives both factual information about Jesus and tips on how to make practical use of that knowledge.
4. Miracles, which are tangible, physical demonstrations of God’s care.
5. The gifts of repentance and forgiveness, which repair the breach in our friendship and restore open communications.
6. Journals and memories. When we recall things that God did for us in the past, our gratitude rises up again.
7. The Sacraments, like communion, confession, and Baptism
8. Prayer and other forms of communication.

Communication is key. The book of Job lists many ways in which God communicates with us and we with him. Some are always available while others are special channels initiated by God. However, even those means that we cannot employ by our own unaided will can be requested. Job cried out in great distress for God to appear and speak to him face to face, and in the end, God showed up. Here are some of the means found in Job:

1. Prayer
2. Worship in song and silence
3. Listening to wise elders
4. Observing God’s glory in nature
5. Reading the Word of God
6. Fasting
7. Offering sacrifices
8. Serving others
9. Suffering
10. Dreams
11. Visions
12. Miracles
13. Angelic visitation
14. Theophany or Christophany

Means not mentioned in Job that are practiced by some Christians but questioned by others are:

1. Veneration of Jesus, Mary and the saints via the mediation of icons
2. Visitations by the Blessed Virgin Mary
3. Practicing the presence of God, a mystical union, an interpretation of what is meant to abide in Christ or be connected to the vine via contemplation
4. The Beatific vision

Earlier I said that we can pray to God to reach out to us in an unusual way, a direct and miraculous way. He is not obligated to do so, but delights in showing himself to those who seek him earnestly. A decade ago I undertook a fast. For three years I prayed and fasted every Monday with a single prayer, “Lord, show me your glory.” How did God respond? Not with a dream or vision or miracle or visitation. Instead, the Lord magnified my ability to understand the Bible and greatly increased my desire to read it. The parameters of his care are decided by Him.

Last summer, reflecting on all the ways that God can communicate with us, I fixated upon angelic visitation. I had never seen an angel and know nobody who has. Angels had never been a topic of great interest to me. For some reason I chose to pray this: “Lord, I know you do nothing gratuitously, but if I should ever find myself in a situation where only an angel can help me, please send an angel.” It was an unusual prayer and I would never have given it another thought until I fell through the ice in December while skating, broke my arm and spent 25 minutes in freezing water. God sent a human angel, a woman with the fire department on a sledge, and she rescued me. Erica Poitras was the angel, which means messenger, to deliver God’s grace to me.

That was not the only angel he sent, though. Days later, while waiting for the day of my surgery, which would require a plate and seven screws to repair the damage, I lay on the couch in severe pain, unable to sleep. The pain medication did nothing. My arm was still dislocated. The delay for surgery was because of a lapse in my health insurance. My new insurance would not kick in until January. I lay on my back, praising the Father for saving my life, but wincing in agony. All of a sudden, I saw a vision of a woman’s face. Without a word, she pulled me close and hugged me. The pain left me immediately and would not return for at least five hours. For the next hour, despite being exhausted, I was filled with a joyful spirit of intercession and prayed for family, friends, church and community. Then I slept.

The woman never spoke a word, but I know whom Jesus sent. He sent his mother Mary to comfort me, and I was comforted.  God answered my prayer from last summer. He did more than I could ask or imagine. I would never have asked Jesus to send Mary, because I am a Baptist!

Be bold and persistent in your prayers. You never know what God will do. And that is how your love for God will grow.

Answer (score 4):

> And hope maketh not ashamed; because the love of God is shed abroad in our hearts by the Holy Ghost which is given unto us. [Romans 5:5 KJV]

The love of God is not something that we can work up from within ourselves. It is shed abroad in our hearts (if we have truly repented, believed and received the Holy Spirit).

> We love him, because he first loved us. [1 John 4:19 KJV]

We love him in return for the love he has for us (if we have been called by grace and have discovered that love for ourselves, in our own experience).

'Love' is not a legal work that is done for reward.

It is the result of A relationship which we have been brought into, by grace and mercy.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. You're not alone.

I'll try to give you an answer that is free from the teachings of a particular religion and draw from the teachings of the Bible alone, but, full disclosure, I'm a member of the [Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-Day Saints](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/), and my views on the matter are influenced by the teachings of that church. If you like what I say, check out what the Church teaches.

---

**Anyways, my answer below.**
TL;DR:
You can nurture a love for a God you can't fully understand by acknowledging His hand in all things, and in cultivating gratitude for all the things He has given you.

---

Your reaction is completely natural. How, indeed, can we love something we cannot comprehend? Let us draw a parallel to nature, and see if the logic carries over. (A method often employed by Jesus: consider the sparrows, the fig tree, etc.)

How does a baby love its mother? Surely there are few creatures more helpless or ignorant than a human baby, yet few of God's creations love so deeply and so purely. Now, how does a baby love something it does not understand?

We may draw a connection between us and a baby. We know similarly little about the nature of God than a baby does the nature of its mother.

Therefore, we see an example that love does not need to come from understanding alone. If this is the case, where does love originate from?

Let us refer back to the baby. The baby loves mother because of, among other things:

- The warmth of mother's arms
- The feeling of love in mother's voice
- The feeling of fullness from mother's milk
- The feeling of peace from mother's song

The question then stands: Can we, too, feel love towards someone we can't truly understand, as babies do towards their mothers? It appears so, yes.

Let us follow the example of little children in this as Jesus instructed in Matthew 18:3; this is done by feeling joy because of the things God has given you (and as an adult, you may have to intentionally foster gratitude to do this):

- The warmth of the sunshine that He embraces you with
- The feeling of love in the tender words He spoke to you through Jesus Christ, and his other prophets (like Paul)
- The feeling of fullness that He can give our lives, or even the feeling of physical fullness after a good meal (As the earth, and all things thereon are his, including food!)
- The feeling of peace in the songs and poems written by his inspired servants that detail our safety and salvation in his arms

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on asking and answering questions.